# How do I add a variable in the middle of an href?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to take this link below which is a search query and pull the item sku in woocommerce to be put in place of  when they click the link. The code below is used to display a link in our store whenever an item is up for auction. How would I add $product->get_sku() in the middle of an href? I've tried multiple ways. Everything I find online about variable href only shows if the entire href is a variable. Any help is greatly appreciated.

https://www.wirebids.com/search?q="VARIABLE HERE"&open_closed=open

```
// Display Auction Link When 'auction' is in the category
function so_43372512_maybe_show_auction_link(){
if( has_term( 'auction', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    echo ' <style type="text/css">
                .woocommerce div.product form.cart, .woocommerce div.product p.cart {
                display:none ; }
                .woocommerce div.product p.price, .woocommerce div.product span.price {
                display:none ; }
                .woocommerce div.product p.stock {
                display:none ; }
                .product_meta {
                margin-top:20px;
                }
            </style>';
    echo 'Click This Button To View The Lot         ';
    $skusearch = $product-get_sku();
    echo '<a id="auction" style="font-size:100%;color:#fff;padding:.618em 1em;border-radius:3px;background-color:#ed1c24;font-weight:700;" href="https://www.wirebids.com/search?q=' . $skusearch . '&open_closed=open" target="blank">' . __ ( 'On Auction Now!', 'your-plugin' ) . '</a>';
}
}'
```

I updated my code to show you what I have going on. Adding the variable where I have it breaks the function. Feeling pretty dumb right now lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
$VARIABLENAME = $product->get_sku();
echo '<a href="https://www.wirebids.com/search?q=' . $VARIABLENAME . '&open_closed=open" style="font-size:100%;color:#fff;padding:.618em 1em;border-radius:3px;background-color:#ed1c24;" target="blank">' . __ ( 'On Auction Now!', 'your-plugin' ) . '</a>'
```

Or swap the quotes you are using to do

```
$VARIABLENAME = $product->get_sku();
echo "<a href='https://www.wirebids.com/search?q=$VARIABLENAME&open_closed=open' style='font-size:100%;color:#fff;padding:.618em 1em;border-radius:3px;background-color:#ed1c24;' target='blank'>" . __ ( 'On Auction Now!', 'your-plugin' ) . '</a>'
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm finally not getting a broken page. But I need to use $product->get_sku() and when I add the get sku part it breaks the link. Could I just define a variable for get sku and use that there?

Comment: There you go, is that ok

Comment: ok, this is going to sound really dumb, but where should I put the      $VARIABLENAME = $product->get_sku(); in my function? When I add it above the href it breaks the page again.

Comment: It's working aside from adding the variable. Any time I try to add a variable in my function it breaks the function. Pretty sure I'm just being dumb. So once I get the variable defined I'm pretty sure I'll be good to go

Comment: It was a syntax error because I'm stupid. Thanks a ton!! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$var = $product->get_sku();
echo '<a style="font-size:100%;color:#fff;padding:.618em 1em;border-radius:3px;background-color:#ed1c24;" href="https://www.wirebids.com/search?q=' . $var . '&open_closed=open" target="blank">' . __ ( 'On Auction Now!', 'your-plugin' ) . '</a>';
```